# how to convert/show js var(video tag) in dynamic modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, video

I want to show an apparat video in my dynamic modal but my code doesn't work.

My dynamic modal code

```
var html = '' +
    '<div class="modal fade" id="Modal' + id + '" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">' +
    '   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"> ' +
    '       <div class="modal-content"> ' +
    '           <div class="modal-header">' +
    '               <div class="col-md-1 left">' +
    '                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" style="float: left">' +
    '                       <i class="material-icons">clear</i>' +
    '                   </button>' +
    '               </div>' +
    '               <div class="col-md-11">' +
    '                   <h4 class="modal-title right text-right">' + title + '</h4>' +
    '               </div>' +
    '           </div>' +
    '           <div class="modal-body">' + 
    '               <div class="row">' +
    '                   <div class="col-md-6">' +
    '                       ' + video +
    '                   </div>' +
    '                   <div class="col-md-6">' +
    '                       <div class="row">' + 
    '                           <h4 class="text-right" style="padding: 10px">' + about + '</h4>' +
    '                       </div>' +
    '                   </div>' +
    '               </div>' + 
    '               <div class="row">' + 
    '                   <div class="row text-right">' +
    '                       <div class="col-md-10">' +
    '                       </div>' +
    '                       <div class="col-md-2">' +
    '                           <h3>روزومه</h3>' +
    '                       </div>' +
    '                   </div>' +
    '                   <div class="row">' +
    '                       <div class="col-md-2">' +
    '                       </div>' +
    '                       <div class="col-md-10 text-right right">' +
    '                           ' + rezomeh +
    '                       </div>' +
    '                   </div>' +
    '               </div>' +
    '           </div>' +
    '           <div class="modal-footer">' +
    '               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">' +
    '                   <b>نمایش کامل مشخصات</b>' +
    '               </button>' +
    '           </div>' +
    '       </div>' +
    '   </div>' +
    '</div>';
document.getElementById("show_modal").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("show_modal").innerHTML = html;
var modal_id = "#Modal" + id;
$(modal_id).modal();
```

And my video var content is

```
<div id="15112483129479291"><script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://www.aparat.com/embed/OVHv9?data[rnddiv]=15112483129479291&data[responsive]=yes"></script></div>
```

In result: video `div` is empty

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [video](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) tag or an iframe if you are using older browsers.

Video Tag:

```
var video = '<div id="15112483129479291"> +
'<video width="320" height="240" controls>'+
'<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">' +
 </video>';
```